# MDX how to achieve this?

Tags: count, ssas, mdx

I have the following mdx query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[FlowAmount] } ON COLUMNS,
```

`NON EMPTY`
`{ ([Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter].ALLMEMBERS *`
`[TransferCase].[Tfr Case Ref].[Tfr Case Ref].ALLMEMBERS *`
`[Dim Wrappers].[Fac Group].[Fac Group].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS`

`FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[FY 13/14] } ) ON COLUMNS`

`FROM [Cube])`

It returns the following:

Q1  TF1 GIA 1000

Q1  TF2 GIA 2500

Q1  TF3 ISA 100

Q1  TF4 GIA 100

How can I get a count of the Tfr Case Refs by Fac Group and summed Flow Amount?

Q1 GIA 3 2600

Q1 ISA 1 100

So in SQL
`Select Fiscal Quarter, Fac Group , count(distinct TfrCaseRef), Sum(FlowAmount)
Group by Fiscal Quarter, Fac Group`

TransferCase is a Fact Dimension based on Fact Table which contains the FlowAmount measure.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Count Refs] AS
  COUNT(
   Distinct(
     EXISTING [TransferCase].[Tfr Case Ref].[Tfr Case Ref].Members
   )
  )
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
  { 
   [Measures].[FlowAmount]
  ,Measures.[Count Refs]  
  } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
  DESCENDANTS(
     [Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[FY 13/14]
   , [Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter]
  )
  *[Dim Wrappers].[Fac Group].[Fac Group].ALLMEMBERS 
  ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

I've used the `DESCENDANTS` function to get all the quarters related to FY 13/14. Hopefully a little easier to read than the sub-query.